# Wait for several objects to emit a signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I know how to wait for a single object to finish, using

```
QEventLoop eventLoop;
connect(&obj, SIGNAL(finished()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
eventLoop.exec();
```

But now I have several objects which I want to 'run' in parallel, so I need to wait until all of them have sent their `finished()` SIGNALs.

This would be like a signals-and-slots version of the WaitForMultipleObjects WinApi function.

How should I go about doing that?

Comment: I would connect the finished signal to a class that counts the # of signals received and emits quit() when it hits the expected count.

Comment: Hm, if I go that route, I could just add a local variable that does that. Unless you mean for code reuse and such.

Comment: Yes I mean for code reuse. Although a local variable incremented on each finished signal will work as well

Comment: sashoalm @drescherjm seems to have pretty much nailed the simplest solution, that's the way I do my collation unless there is a need for more granular control.

Comment: If you have a generic class Operation, Job etc. that has the finished() signal, you could use the composite pattern to group jobs. See KDE's KCompositeJob for inspiration: http://api.kde.org/4.0-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kdecore/html/classKCompositeJob.html KCompositeJob itself is a KJob and can contain KJobs as sub jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would connect the finished signal to a class that counts the # of signals received and emits quit() when it hits the expected count.

Something like this:

```
class EmitIfCountReached : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
   EmitIfCountReached( int expectedCount, QObject* parent =  nullptr) : m_expected(expectedCount), m_count(0), QObject(parent) {}
signals:
   void finished();

protected slots:
   void increment() {
      m_count++;
      if (m_count >= m_expected) {
         emit finished();
      }
   }

protected:
   int m_count;
   int m_expected;
};
```

Comment: `CompositeJob` would be a more apt name - it's from @Frank's comment about KCompositeJob, but great answer, thanks.

Comment: I was thinking of using it for more than jobs. For example the number of questions answered on a form. Maybe the user has to answer 5 out of 7 questions to go on to the next set of questions.